# Java Swing trying iterate over a list and draw eachline

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I am trying to figure out how to iterate over incoming data points and draw a graph on a JPanel as data points come in.  To start I am just trying to iterate a List of DataPoints and draw each line (calling repaint).  I have attempted several ways to do this but no luck....

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    protected int x1 = 0;
    protected int x2 = 0;
    protected int y1 = 0;
    protected int y2 = 0;


    public MyPanel(){
        iteratePoints();
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(new MyPanel());

         }
      });

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        System.out.println("In print");
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    };

    private void iteratePoints(){
        System.out.println("iteratepoints");
        ArrayList<DataGrid> dataList = new ArrayList<DataGrid>();
        dataList.add(new DataGrid(0,4));
        dataList.add(new DataGrid(5,14));
        dataList.add(new DataGrid(10,1));
        dataList.add(new DataGrid(15,10));
        dataList.add(new DataGrid(20,14));
        dataList.add(new DataGrid(25,1));

        for(int i = 0; i<dataList.size(); i++)
        {

            x2 = dataList.get(i).x;
            y2 = dataList.get(i).y;

            this.repaint();  
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
        }

    }

    private class DataGrid
    {
        public int x, y;
        DataGrid(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Make your list a field of your class, instead of those x and y variables. In your paintComponent method, iterate on the lines and drow each of them.

Comment: The problem would be, the points will eventually come from an eye tracker (every frame).  So I need a way to draw each line as they come in.  If I add each line to a List and iterate it in the paintComponent then each frame the entire list would have to be re-iterated over and re-drawn.  Is that the best way to do this?

Comment: That can be sufficient. You can also paint to a BufferedImage as camickr told in his answer.

Comment: @jbg2408, why don't you read the answer and follow the link. The link provides advantages and disadvantages to each approach suggested. Then you can decide for yourself which approach you think is relevant for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the List of Points in the `paintComponent()` method, not in the "iteratePoints()" method.

With your current approach every repaint will simply clear the previous painting and only paint a line representing your last x/y values.

The other option is to paint directly to a `BufferedImage`.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both approaches.